# How to perform click event on overlapping Google map makers alternatively in jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As I am getting the same latitude and longitude from database for different markers, the markers are getting pin on each other, now I want to perform click event on makers alternatively, but only the top marker pin is clicked, how can I click the back one .

Comment: possible duplicate of [allow user to move marker position back (z-index?) in google maps custom map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279202/allow-user-to-move-marker-position-back-z-index-in-google-maps-custom-map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier is the solution: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

> Ever noticed how, in Google Earth, marker pins that overlap each
>   other spring apart gracefully when you click them, so you can pick the
>   one you meant?
>
> And ever noticed how, when using the Google Maps API, the same thing
>   doesn’t happen?
>
> This code makes Google Maps API version 3 map markers behave in that
>   Google Earth way (minus the animation). Small numbers of markers (yes,
>   up to 8) spiderfy into a circle. Larger numbers fan out into a more
>   space-efficient spiral.

Demo page is here: http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html

Comment: I am getting the markers pinned at exactly the same location due to the same latitude & longitude values coming from database . And when the Markers get Spiderfier  (Markers Expands or Separate from each other) I also want to perform click operation on maker. But in the example markers get collapsed when click is performed second time.

Comment: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier: `keepSpiderfied (default: false)`. By default, the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier works like Google Earth, in that when you click a spiderfied marker, the markers unspiderfy before any other action takes place. Since this can make it tricky for the user to work through a set of markers one by one, you can override this behaviour by setting the keepSpiderfied option to true.